# A program that will show only negative numbers

Tags: c++, computer-science

I need to code a program that will show only negative numbers from the given vector. I did it but it's not working. Can someone please tell me why this code won't work?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
     int const m = 6;
     int A[m] = { 1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6 };
     int i;

     std::cout << "A[negative]={";
     for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
         if (A[i] < 0)
             std::cout << A[i];
     std::cout << "}" << std::endl;`
     system("PAUSE");
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Works for me, printing out `A[negative]={-2-4-6}`. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: `system("PAUSE");` Isn't a portable thing, what's your development environment?

Comment: _"and I need it urgent"_ Sure, no mission critical task could be more urgent than solving this first. Task forces come up here now. Post a [MCVE] please to get helped actually.

Comment: This code is fine, maybe you forgot to #include <iostream> or you have problems with system("PAUSE"). Could you specify how your code doesn't work? What errors do you get if you get any?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ serial commenting eh? :p On topic: the loop looks fine, the problem must be elsewhere. Post the output you're getting, OP.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. There's no error inside the code, but when I try to run it, an error keeps showing up. I checked the #include <whatevers> and there's nothing wrong with them. By the way, thank you, a lot for trying to help.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and sorry if I'm acting panically.

Comment: @MuhamedShabani Which error specifically? Please edit that into your question. The code sample you're showing isn't complete. Either it doesn't compile already, or you have reduced/simplified it to much and there's code you have that causes the error and you don't show us.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ here's the code.

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int const m = 6;

 int A[m] = { 1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6 };

 int i;

 std::cout << "A[negative]={";
 for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
 if (A[i] < 0)
 std::cout << A[i];
 std::cout << "}" << std::endl;

 system("PAUSE");
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Comment: @MuhamedShabani You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35785634/edit) your question to improve it. As you might notice providing the full code in comments, isn't very useful.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'll just let it that way. Anyway, thank you again. Btw, are you a programmer? I mean, do you code (in the everyday life)?

Comment: @MuhamedShabani _"I mean, do you code (in the everyday life)?"_ Sure, most of the time. There are also times I have to do requirement analysis, and architecture design documentation. But I'm a whole hearted programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program works fine I only added the `#include <iostream>` as well changed the return statement to the following `return 0;`

I don't know what IDE you are using, but if you are using Visual Studio. It is better to do the following instead of using `system("PAUSE");`

> Go to Project > Properties > Linker > System > SubSystem > then from the dropdown menu choose > Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int const m = 6;

    int A[m] = { 1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6 };

    int i;

    std::cout << "A[negative]={";
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        if (A[i] < 0)
            std::cout << A[i];
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According standards `return 0;` isn't necessary at all for `main()`

Comment: Thank you @πάνταῥεῖ . Honestly, I didn't know, I was told that `int main()` has to return a value I am still learning programming. :)